# How would you structure the class interactions in a physics engine?

Tags: c++, oop, class-hierarchy

I'm writing a physics engine in C++ and I've come to a stop, namely how I should design the class hierarchy. What I'm specifically concerned about is the `World` and `Body` classes. `Body` should expose some details to `World` that `World` then can work on. But at the same time, I don't want users to be able to access all of those properties of `Body`. But I still want users of the engine to be able to change some things in a body. For example, its position. How would you structure this in terms of classes?

Answer (score 0):

Define an `interface` (i.e. a pure virtual class) that specifies what functions you want exposed from `Body`. Have `Body` implement that inteface.

Allow that interface, and not `Body` to be used from `World`.

This pattern is called *composition*.

Comment: So you're talking something like this? http://lpaste.net/6992179433306062848

Comment: No. I'd start by defining the interface. Body implements that interface.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I've solved a similar problem by introducing a special interface for the restricted operations, and inheriting *protectedly* from it. Like this:

```
struct RestrictedBodyFunctions
{
  virtual void step() = 0;

  virtual Body& asBody() = 0;
};


struct Body : protected RestrictedBodyFunctions
{
  static std::unique_ptr<Body> createInWord(World &world)
  {
    auto Body = std::unique_ptr<Body>{new Body()};
    world.addBody(*body);  // cast happens inside Body, it's accessible
    return std::move(body);
  }

  std::string getName() const;
  void setName(std::string name);

protected:
  void step() override
  { /*code here*/ }

  Body& asBody() override
  { return *this; }
};


struct World
{
  void addBody(RestrictedBodyFunctions &body)
  {
    m_bodies.push_back(&body);
  }

  void step()
  {
    for (auto *b : m_bodies)
    {
      myLog << "Stepping << " b->asBody().getName() << '\n';
      b->step();
    }
  }

private:
  std::vector<RestrictedBodyFunctions*> m_bodies;
};
```

That way, users can create `Body` objects using `createInWorld`, but they only get a handle to (the public part of) `Body`, while the `World` gets its handle to `RestrictedBodyFunctions`.

Another option you have is to reverse the above idea - provide a restricted public interface `PublicBody`, and have `Body` derive from `PublicBody`. Your internal classes will use the full `Body`, while factory functions make sure only `PublicBody`-typed handles are available to the clients. This alternative is a more simple design, but provides less control over who can access the full functionality.

Comment: I want World to have full access to the internals of `Body`. But come to think of it, there are probably some other classes like `Contact` and `Joint` which I want to have full access to it too.

Comment: @user3399634 For "full access to internals," you can just use `friend`; but that's an extremely tight coupling. I'll add another option to the answer.

Comment: Yeah, but I think the system won't benefit from decoupling `World` and `Body` anyway. I kind of see `Body` as technically being a part of `World`, only being a separate class because I want to expose a nice interface. But yeah you're probably right. If I want to do something like this, then why not just use `friend` instead of beating around the bush.

Let's say it like this: The properties like `position`, I kind of want those to act like they're `internal` (like in .NET). What is the best alternative for that, `friend` or restricted interfaces?